# remove carriage return character from php tidy repaired html string

Tags: php, html, htmltidy, repair

I would want check if string is a valid xhtml/html. 
I have some html string get by tinymce editor. I would want in first time before save it into mysql database check if this html string is valid. I'm trying php tidy library:

```
    $html = '<div> <a href="#">a link</a> this is test <p>close tag error</p> </p> <p></p>';
    $tidy = new \tidy();
    $clean = $tidy->repairString($html,array(
        'output-xml' => true,
        'input-xml' => true
    ));
```

but it output this:

```
<div>\n<a href="#">a link</a>this is test \n<p>close tag error</p>other text \n<p></p></div>
```

so tags are closed correctly but tidy put /n characters.
How can repair html without carriage return character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use htmlspecialhars_decode() to disable displaying of special characters...

```
$clean = htmlspecialchars_decode($clean);
```

Answer (score 2):

While not perfect (since it could destroy any actual carridge returns you have) the quick answer would be:

```
 $string = str_replace('\n', '', $originalString);
```

Comment: `str_replace('\n', '', $originalString);` will remove only the `\n` strings in text. The real carridge return characters will stay in tact, unless used with double quotes like this: `str_replace("\n", '', $originalString);`